# 2D Array in an If Statement

Tags: java, arrays, methods, compiler-errors, boolean

I've created a 2D Array in Java that stores seatnumbers(row, column). I've initialized the array so that all values start out as 0, and if the seat is later occupied using another method Sit, the value at that coordinate is 1.

Here is the intializing:

```
int[][] seatlist= new int[FIRSTCLASS/3][3];           


for (int i=0; i<= FIRSTCLASS/3; i++) 
     {  
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++) 
      { 
         seatlist[i][j]=0;

       }
    }
```

and here is my method:

```
public boolean canSit(int seatrow, int seatcolumn)
{ 
    if(seatlist[seatrow-1][seatcolumn-1]==0) 
    { 
        return true;
    } 
    else 
        return false; 
}
```

When I try compiling, I keep getting an "array required, but int found" error on the if statement line.  I can't identify the problem- can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the declaration for `seatlist`?

Comment: @Code-Guru I've just added it!

Comment: are you sure about   "i<= FIRSTCLASS/3"... shouldn't it be "i< FIRSTCLASS/3"?

Comment: First of all, `for (int i=0; i<= FIRSTCLASS/3; i++)` should be `<` rather than `<=`

Comment: How does `canSit` get access to `seatlist`?

Comment: @BlackBox Missed that, and yes just corrected it!

Comment: @BlackBox I declared seatlist a class variable. Would I have to return 'seatlist' after the for loop for 'canSit' to have access?

Comment: Assuming all the code you've shown are called from non-static methods and `seatlist` is declared outside of the method, it will be fine as it is.

Comment: I've fixed my problem. I declared my arrays outside the method but I filled them in another method, which was causing the error message.

Comment: And this is the reason you should always post relevant code ;), hopefully next time you will remember this. gl

Comment: @BlackBox Yup, learned my lesson. Thanks though for going through this with me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Integer[][] seatlist= new Integer[FIRSTCLASS/3][3];
```

or

```
int[FIRSTCLASS/3][3] seatlist;
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized I was only declaring it as a local variable instead of a class variable :)